# Exempt an attribute in require method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I am maintaining a current Web Application (Ruby on Rails).

Our client wanted me to add this attributes `contacts_attributes: [:id, :stock_holding_status]` to the method below:

```
def meeting_log_params
params.require(:meeting_log).permit(
  :id,
  :stock_id,
  :ir_meeting_id,
  :start_at,
  :end_at,
  :kind,
  :meeting_type,
  :request_agent_company,
  :request_agent_name,
  :minute_taker,
  :subject,
  :content,
  :memo,
  :rating,
  :country,
  :city,
  :attachment_1,
  :remove_attachment_1,
  :attachment_2,
  :remove_attachment_2,
  :attachment_3,
  :remove_attachment_3,
  interviewers_attributes: [
    :id,
    :meeting_log_id,
    :resource_id,
    :resource_type,
    :_destroy
  ],
  speakers_attributes: [
    :id,
    :meeting_log_id,
    :resource_id,
    :resource_type,
    :_destroy
  ],
  meeting_log_contacts_attributes: [
    :stock_id,
    :company_name,
    :name,
  ],
  ir_guests_attributes: [
    :stock_id,
    :department,
    :title,
    :last_name,
    :first_name,
    :department_en,
    :title_en,
    :last_name_en,
    :first_name_en,
  ]
)
end
```

It is just that it returns me a 422 error (which means unprocessable entity) every time I used the added attribute on this method below.

```
Contact.update_stock_holding_statuses(meeting_log_params[:contacts_attributes])
```

I think it is because of the `required(:meeting_log)` that was before the `permit` method. Can you tell me how to **exempt** the `required(:meeting_log)` if I am going to use the added attribute on certain methods?

Like what I have in mind is like this:

```
params.require(:meeting_log ? :meeting_log : nil).permit( <all_attributes>)
```

I tried using **ternary** operators to **exempt**/disable the required part for me to use the added attribute which is `contacts_attributes: [:id, :stock_holding_status]` on a specific method and prevent the 422 from interfering. But it didn't work.

Any suggestions please.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply

```
permitted_attributes = [:id,
  :stock_id,
  :ir_meeting_id,
  :start_at,
  :end_at,
  :kind,
  ...
]

def meeting_log_params 
  meeting_log ? params.require(:meeting_log).permit(permitted_params) : params.permit(:permitted_params)
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if the input parameters do not match `require.permit`, then you will get code 400 (not 422).
Code 422 is most likely related to the validation of the model when inside the update_stock_holding_statuses method.

Comment: Actually, there is a separate method which contains the input parameters our client wanted us to add. 

def contact_params
    params.permit(
      contacts_attributes: [
        :id,
        :stock_holding_status,
      ]
    )
  end

This method works and doesn't return a 422 error.  It is just that our client wanted to put all the attributes/parameters in a single method. So is it by modifying the validation of the model going to make it work?

Comment: If you plan to create / update contacts via the parameters of the meeting_log_params method, then you need to add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :contacts ' for the MeetingLog model (more information here https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: if the input parameters do not match `require.permit`, it'll raise `UnpermittedParameters` error